# MYSQL - check a time and execute query

Tags: mysql, sql

I'd like (if it possible) check a time and if time = special time, make update of the table.

My idea:

```
select current_time()
if current_time = 15:19 
{
   update tasks set finished = replace (finished, '1', '0')
}
```

Do you have any ideas???

Answer (score 2):

Use an [event](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events.html) for that

```
delimiter //
CREATE EVENT IF NOT EXISTS your_event
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY 
STARTS  '2014-07-04 15:19:00'
ON COMPLETION PRESERVE ENABLE
DO
    update tasks 
    set finished = replace (finished, '1', '0');
//
```

It will be executed automatically every day on the defined time.

Comment: Ok! Thanks, but I will add this part of code to website on the PHP.
How bind for PHP?

Comment: $sql = mysqli_query($con, "CREATE EVENT IF NOT EXISTS your_event
    ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY 
    STARTS  '2014-07-04 15:19:00'
    ON COMPLETION PRESERVE ENABLE
    DO
        update tasks 
        set finished = replace (finished, '1', '0')"); is it true?

Comment: Look - http://s1.radikali.ru/uploads/2014/7/4/d53d7bd61e6f2c515bf16d7cccbfb541-full.png - Finished has 3 row - Did query - http://s1.radikali.ru/uploads/2014/7/4/4fefeba01b0c176aa001937de51685ef-full.png - and check a table - http://s1.radikali.ru/uploads/2014/7/4/5a005d5f1fed35403697b264f750c455-full.png - Finished the same (((