# mysql workbench procedure calculation

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, mysql-workbench

I am currently struggling to wrap my head around this problem.

In my database i have a table called Books_out_on_loan with columns of (book_borrow_id, member_id, employee_id, isbn, date_issued, date_due, date_returned, amount_of_fine)

I need to run a procedure every 24 hours to add an amount of R1.50 per day per book loaned out by each member and store it on amount_of_fine.

In java it would look something like this: (calculating only 1 book, i dont know how it would work for multiple books[using isbn maybe?])

```
for each member_id
    {
        for each isbn
        {
            if(date_returned==null && date_due < Date.now())
            {
                amount_of_fine = amount_of_fine + 1.5
            }
        }
    }
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

The update statement inside the procedure would be

```
update Books_out_on_loan 
set amount_of_fine = amount_of_fine + 1.5
where date_returned is null
```

That would add the fine to every loaned book that has no return date - hence is not returned yet.

For how to create an event that executes every day see [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24575435/575376).

Comment: how do i interval it to run every 24 hours?

Comment: Task scheduler/cron job/sql job is what you must looking for

Comment: MySQL Event is the mechanism

Comment: How would one go about creating an event in mysql? @juergend